# HelpDesk solution for Wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

Is there a help desk solution plugin (free or paid) for Wordpress?

Ideally a visitor would be able to create a ticket from the WP site and the admin would see it via email and in the admin portal of WP. Also offer the option for invoicing per ticket.

**Edit:** The plugin has to play well with my theme without having to alter anything with the exception of adding shortcodes for the helpdesk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking at the [WordPress Advanced Ticket System plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wats/).  The free version has an admin interface to submit tickets but front end ticket submission requires the [paid version](http://www.ticket-system.net/features/).

Answer (score 1):

How about google? http://getqualitycontrol.com/

Comment: That's more of a theme rather than a plugin. I did Google the topic, but there seems to be a plethora of solutions but many seem shady or don't offer all things I'm looking for.

Comment: First: There's a commercial solution comming (see google). Second: Actually there's no difference between a theme and a plugin except from the folder location. Third: You could still copy the relevant parts of it and integrate them into your own theme/plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I use an end to end solution that includes support desk, project management, billing, and CRM for my clients. Free 14 day trial. If you are a developer, this one really fits the bill.
http://worketc.com

Comment: That looks like a standalone product and doesn't integrate into Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [WPHelpDesk](http://wphelpdesk.com) plugin it does not require integration with theme at all.